# Report "in-stock" configurable products that are actually out-of-stock

Tags: configurable-product, product-list, stock

When all of a configurable product's associated products go out of stock, the configurable product's availability doesn't change. It'll stay listed as **in-stock** until you manually change it. (This is stupid, but default behavior.)

I'm looking to create a page that will list out all of these products for me. Basically, I'd like to create a page that shows all configurable products. Filter that list to show only products with **in-stock** status. And then filter that to show only ones that don't have any in-stock associated products (maybe with an `isSaleable` check).

Before I reinvent this particular wheel, has anyone built such a page?

*Note: I found the opposite code, which may be helpful to someone: https://gist.github.com/arosenhagen/3844732 - This shows configurable products that are set to be 'out of stock' that have in-stock associated products.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built the page - you can find it all in this gist: https://gist.github.com/sam327/11380448

Grabs all configurable products. Then sets up a table: Product Name, Magento ID, "Is Saleable" check, Stock Status (on the config product level), and Associated Product stock check.

I may revise the page to drop any items that are **in-stock** or **out-of-stock** across the board, so that it only lists the items that need human intervention. But this is good enough for my purposes.